# What is the fastest way to search the maximum element in a stack in Java?

Tags: java, search, data-structures, stack

I have a problem in which I have to search for the maximum element in a stack. I've created my own stack class and used the following approach:

```
   Node node = top; //created a new node which points to the top of stack

   int max = node.data;  //max contains the value of the top node

   while(node != null) {
           if(node.data > max) {
              max = node.data;
           }
           node = node.next;
    }

   //Print the value of max.
```

Can anybody suggest a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Unless your stack is somehow sorted there is no faster way than O(n)!? You could use a multithreaded solution, but that might be it.

Answer (score 3):

Maintain two stack :

1. consist of all Nodes.
2. always keep Max node at top of it, which makes it easier to get max element every time.

The code goes like this :

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class StackWithMax extends Stack<Integer> {

Stack<Integer> s2;

public StackWithMax() {
    s2 = new Stack<Integer>();      
}

public void push(int value){
    if (value >= max()) {
        s2.push(value);
    }
    super.push(value);
}

public Integer pop() {
    int value = super.pop();
    if (value == max()) {
        s2.pop();           
    }
    return value;
}

public int max() {
    if (s2.isEmpty()) {
        return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    } else {
        return s2.peek();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you do it like this why not simply save an `int max`in the stack class instead of another stack!?

Comment: @Xander If you just save one `max`, then when you pop an element, you have to go through the whole stack to figure out the `max` again.

Comment: @Xander  than we have to go through whole stack to find max again.

Comment: @xander when an element is removed from the stack and if it's the max, you would need to iterate over the whole stack to find the previous second largest value which is the new max...

Comment: This is an interesting and creative solution.  It's hard to think of a use case where it would be more efficient than xander's suggestion, though.  I'm sure such uses cases exist, but they'd be obscure and probably never occur in practice.

Comment: ok that's a good point, but I guess it depends on how you want to use the stack then. If you don't care about double the memory consumption (worst case) or if you rarely "pop" the max element I'd say you have to evaluate the use case first.

Comment: The fact that you don't properly override the push method makes this very error prone.

Comment: @EvanDarke good point.  The method parameter should be `Integer` instead of `int`, and it should return `Integer`.  Also, it should have an `@Override` annotation so that the compiler can tell if you're not overriding it properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with using an extra space, we can do getMax() in O(1) time. The idea is to use a PriorityQueue based on a comparator that returns the maximum of two elements. Your PriorityQueue will consist of elements arranged ina sorted way based on your comparator. Anytime you push an element in your stack, you push the maximum element corresponding to that element in the PriorityQueue as well. Lets take an example:

Suppose in your stack you are pushing the element 3. Then in your priorityQueue pQ, you would offer 3. At this time, 3 will be the max element corresponding to 3 in the stack.

Lets insert 5 in stack S. Offer 5 in pQ. Since 5 > 3, order of elements in pQ will be 5 3. 
Lets push 4 in S. Offer 4 in pQ as well. pQ will now contain elements: 5 4 3. If you do getMax(), you get head of pQ which takes O(1) time since maximum element is always at top of pQ.

In case of S.pop(), you can remove the corresponding popped element from pQ as well in O(1) time if you store the pQ in the form of LinkedList. Hence, all these operations would take O(1) time really.

Going by same logic, you can also do popMax() too in O(1) time. Just return the head of pQ and delete the corresponding node from Stack as well, which again can be done in O(1) of time.

Here is how the structure of both can be:

```
public class Node{
    int data;
    Node next;
    Node(int data){
        this.data = data;
        next = null;
    }
}

PriorityQueue<Node> pQ = new PriorityQueue<Node>();
Stack<Node> S = new Stack<Node>();
```